# Python list comprehension for identifying and modifying a sequence

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a method which iterates over a list of numbers, and identifies for sequences of 0, non-zero, 0 and then 'normalizes' the value inbetween to 0.

Here is my code:

```
for index in range(len(array)-2):
    if array[index] == 0 and array[index + 1] != 0 and array[index + 2] == 0:
        array[index + 1] = 0
```

This currently works fine, and I have further methods to detect sequences of 0, nz, nz, 0 etc.

I've been looking into list comprehensions in Python, but having trouble figuring out where to start with this particular case. Is it possible to do this using list comprehension?

Comment: when you say `normalize`, you mean set the value to be zero?

Comment: So a value between two zeros becomes zero?

Comment: yes thats correct.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have written.  You could do something with iterators, `next`, `zip` and a list comprehension, but it would be more complicated.

Comment: Not all `for` loops can (or should) be turned in to list comprehensions. In this case, you aren't simply applying a common expression to each element of your list; you are modifying an element based on its context in the list. This `for` loop is far better than any list comprehension you might come up with that does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments and advice given, it seems that my original code is the most simplest and perhaps most efficient way of performing the process. No further answers are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like

```
new_array = [ 0 if (array[i-1] == array[i+1] == 0)
                else array[i]
                for i in range(1,len(array)-1) ]

# More readable, but far less efficient
array = array[0] + new_array + array[-1]

# More efficient, but less readable
# array[1:-1] = new_array
```

I've adjusted the range you iterate over to add some symmetry to the condition, and take advantage of the fact that you don't really need to check the value of `array[i]`; if it's 0, there's no harm in explicitly setting the new value to 0 anyway.

Still, this is not as clear as your original loop, and unnecessarily creates a brand new list rather than modifying your original list only where necessary.

Comment: Doesn't this chop the first and last elements?  Perhaps slice assignment to fix: `array[1:-1] = ...`

Comment: I agree, this looks much more difficult to read than my original code. I was hoping for something more elegant and efficient, since I have about 6 of these types of methods which look for continous patterns in my time series list data.

Comment: Yup, forgot to handle the edge cases. I'll fix.

Answer (score -2):

Not everything should be a comprehension.  If you wish to be torturous though:

```
def f(a):
    [a.__setitem__(i + 1, 0) for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:], a[2:])) 
     if x == z == 0 and y != 0]
```

Then

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4]
>>> f(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4]
```